# Is it possible to export a list of lists to and still maintain it originally?

Tags: python, list, export, text-files

```
textFileLists = [[str1, str2, str3], [str1, str2, str3], [str1, str2, str3]]    
data = open('Data for A11.1.txt', 'r')    
read = data.read()    
new = []    
for i in read:       
      new.append(i.split('\n'))

print(new)
```

Is it possible to export a list of lists to and still maintain it originally?

Comment: You probably want to [**`pickle`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) it.

Comment: I thought pickle was for only dictionaries.

Comment: @AnthonyMalachiParkerIII Pickle can pickle any Python data type.

Comment: How can I use pickle for a text file that already exists?